# How to change LAN IP in windows 10 using Python 3.6 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip

I want to change my PC LAN IP, I am using below script. But it's not updating. Please help on the same.

```
import wmi
import socket

nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True) 
nic = nic_configs[0]

ip = u'192.168.1.197'
subnetmask = u'255.255.255.0'
gateway = u'192.168.1.250'

nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress = [ip], SubnetMask = [subnetmask])
nic.SetGateways(DefaultIPGateway = [gateway])

print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
```

Result: 192.168.1.37